Decomposition theorem for resolution of surface singularity
I’ve asked this question on MSE but I don’t get an answer, so I’m trying to ask here.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914142/decomposition-theorem-for-resolution-of-surface-singularities
In the section 3.1 of the paper Intersection forms,topology of maps and motives decomposition for resolution of three folds by de Cataldo and Migliorini:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504554
They prove the following theorem: Let $f: X\to Y$ be a proper birational map of quasi-projective surfaces, $X$ smooth, $Y$ normal. There is a canonical isomorphism:
$Rf_*\mathbb{Q}_X[2]\cong IC_Y\oplus R^2f_*\mathbb{Q}_X[0]$.
And they work locally on $Y$,more precisely, let’s further assume $(Y, p)$ a germ of an analytic normal surface singularity and $f:(X,f^{-1}(p))\to (Y, p)$ a resolution, here $f^{-1}(p)$ is the exceptional divisor.
Under this setting, we can take the stalk at $p$ on both sides, then we have:
$H^1(f^{-1}(P))\cong H^1(IC_Y)$,
at degree $1$. However, consider $j:Y-p\to Y$ the open embedding, since $j^*Rf\mathbb{Q}_X\cong \mathbb{Q}_{Y-p}$ and $IC_Y=\tau_{\leq -1}Rj_*j^*Rf_*\mathbb{Q}_X[2]$, we have:
$H^{-1}(IC_Y)=R^1(j_*\mathbb{Q}_{Y-p})\cong H^1(Y-p)$.
And $H^1(Y-p)$ contain no information about fiber $f^{-1}(p)$, which seems a contradiction. But I don’t know where do I make the mistake, Can somebody help me to find it out? Thanks in advance.
